# How to write a DB trigger when a new file is created?

Tags: linux, oracle, plsql

I have an application that creates & stores logs inside a folder.
I need to identify new logs, parse them and update DB with contents of parsed file.

How do I identify the new log file and fire the trigger? (Server on unix/linux box)
The log's filename does not contain timestamp. And, I have more than 100 requests falling into the folder within 1 minute.
File name consists of unique order ID & source-destination components.

The structure of the log folder is sorted date wise:

```
X
|__2013
      |__12
          |__31
              |__LOG_FROMCOMP_TOCOMP_ORDERID.TXT
```

I cannot update the application to update the database and the log folder is common to many components.  I should parse the log folder and then update the database accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> " I have more than 100 requests falling into the folder within 1
>   minute"

In other words, you have a poorly designed application which should have a message-based architecture but remains mired in the early 1990s.  Commiserations.

Plus, the filenames have been chosen to be as unhelpful as possible.  Commiserations double plus.

Further bad news: it is hard for the database to work a directory structure like that.  The Oracle security model expects known OS directories; if you're creating a new directory every day that is not something which is sustainable with directory objects, which rules out the use of external tables (the easiest way of loading files into our database).

So, what can be done?  Two choices

1. shell script calling PL/SQL
2. Java stored procedure calling PL/SQL

The shell scripting approach would involve a daemon script fired on a regular basis (via cron or whatever) which figures out the current directory and looks for files which have been added since the last polling.  The shell script needs to store its execution time in a config file.  The wrinkle here is that unix doesn't store the file creation time.  But if you can rely on the files being written once and *never updated* you can use `ls -c` to sort the files and filter them by the stored execution time.

For each file the shell script calls a PL/SQL procedure.  It passes the contents of the file as a CLOB.  The stored procedure processes the file as required.

To control it all from the database you need to use a Java stored procedure to read the directory.  Tom Kyte has a solution which populates a temporary table, which you can adapt to your needs.  [Find it here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584).  Again you'll need to derive the actual directory.

In this approach the JSP is called through a DBMS_JOB and calls a PL/SQL progarm for each file; it passes the full file path and the stored procedure uses UTL_FILE to read the file.  Note this means convincing your DBA to set the UTL_FILE_DIR parameter in the `init.ora` file.  This is deprecated, so expect some resistance.  However, it takes wildcards, so it's the only way of handling the dynamic directory names.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/initparams223.htm).

The JSP will list all the files in the temporary table.  One solution here would be to have a permanent table with the names of all the files processed, and use the MINUS operator to extract the set of unprocessed files.  This would be more reliable than relying on the unix `ctime` in the shell script approach.

---

As you do have a messaging architecture in place you have a third option: instead on dropping individual files in a perpetually changing directory, use advancing queuing.  Obviously sending an additional message does require some changes to the application but I would hope a minimal one.  AQ would definitely be neater than either of the  solutions I proposed above.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/aq_intro.htm#ADQUE0100).

Comment: I have proper MQs and JMS in place which are queueing my requests and processing them. FYI: I have maintained a zero-request-dropout in the last 1.5 years.

Comment: I am trying to implement a new logging mechanism which can do what I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thank you APC. We already have a file walker code snippet to traverse all file paths. Since the order ID is incremental, and we know the sequence of components. we can identify the unprocessed files without much effort. 

Thank you for your inputs. Will take them and work on it.